# How to disable automatic sign in google play games services android unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

as google says when the app starts pops up gpgs sign in, since my app is for children and older ages is necessary a screen neutral age, i did it, but automatic sign in keeps triggerring, it is for unity android, google play games services plugin

i searched and find two questions about it, but both is about android native code not unity plugin

Comment: Is a GPGS required for publishing on Play Market? Could you just get rid of it completely?

Comment: No, but I need for the leaderboard, it's a way to make a competitive game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically the version 11 that i was using is impossible, but version 10 is still possible to use demand sign in
[REFERENCE](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/3258)